# python-vlcを使用してランダム再生を実現したい

Tags: python, python3, mp3

python-vlcを使用して、MediaList内の曲をランダムに再生する方法を探しています。

`random.shuffle`でListを並び替えようとしましたが、
`random`関数がMediaListに対応していないようで
`TypeError: 'MediaList' object does not support item assignment`
と出力され実行できませんでした。

Google等で検索もしてみましたが、望んでいる回答を見つけることができませんでした。

このエラーを治す方法はありますでしょうか？
もしくは、何か他の良い方法はありますでしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

```
import vlc
import os
import glob
import random as rm

pydir=os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.chdir(pydir)
files=glob.glob("music/*/*.mp3")


instance = vlc.Instance()
media_list = instance.media_list_new()
media_list_player = instance.media_list_player_new()

# 曲を追加
for i ,d in enumerate(files):
    media_list.add_media(d)

rm.shuffle(media_list)

media_list_player.set_media_list(media_list)

a=input()

if a == "normal":
    media_list_player.play()
elif a == "random":
    ####曲順をシャッフル####
    rm.shuffle(media_list)
    media_list_player.play()
```

エラー

```
File "PATH\test.py", line 19, in <module>
    rm.shuffle(media_list)
File "C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\random.py", line 383, in shuffle
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
    ~^^^
TypeError: 'MediaList' object does not support item assignment
```

**追記**

申し訳ありません、記述不足でした。
通常の再生順とランダムとを使い分けたいのです。

編集前：

```
media_list_player.play()
```

編集後：

```
a=input()

if a == "normal":
    media_list_player.play()
elif a == "random":
    ####曲順をシャッフル####
    rm.shuffle(media_list)
    media_list_player.play()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 基本的な考え方

最終的に「プレイリスト内で曲順がシャッフルされている」事自体がゴールなのであれば、プレイリスト内でシャッフルするのではなく、登録前にファイル一覧をシャッフルするアプローチでも問題ないかなと感じました。
※python-vlcのMediaListオブジェクトが「`add_media`のたびにファイル名をもとにソートする」ような挙動だと意味はないのですが

#### Before:

```py
# 曲を追加
for i ,d in enumerate(files):
    media_list.add_media(d)

rm.shuffle(media_list)
```

#### after:

```
# 事前にシャッフルしてランダム順序にしておく
rm.shuffle(files)

# 曲を追加
for i ,d in enumerate(files):
    media_list.add_media(d)
```

### 追記を受けて

[python-vlcのAPIドキュメント](https://www.olivieraubert.net/vlc/python-ctypes/doc/)を読む限り、MediaListクラスには`__getitem__`はあっても`__setitem__`はありません。（これが理由で質問のエラーが出ている認識）

そのため、python-vlcとして「MediaList内にあるメディアの順序をランダム化する」アプローチの存在には期待しないほうが良さそうです。
※一応、`insert_media`, `remove_media`を使えば擬似的に実現できるかもしれないが、自分の中ではあまり意義がない

また、`input()`の入力を前提をしていることから、現時点ではこのファイル単体で再生が出来れば良いものとすると、
回答としての考え方は特に変わらず、やっぱりアプローチとしては下記のとおりとなります。

- MediaListに追加する前にシャッフルする
- 入力内容でシャッフル実行の有無を決める
- python-vlc上の操作でのランダム再生には期待しない

#### 上記の考え方をもとに処理を並び替える一例

```py
import vlc
import os
import glob
import random as rm

pydir=os.path.dirname(__file__)
os.chdir(pydir)
files=glob.glob("music/*/*.mp3")

a=input()

if a == "normal":
    pass
elif a == "random":
    ####曲順をシャッフル####
    rm.shuffle(files)

instance = vlc.Instance()

# MediaListを用意して曲を追加
media_list = instance.media_list_new()
for i ,d in enumerate(files):
    media_list.add_media(d)

# MediaListPlayerで再生
media_list_player = instance.media_list_player_new()
media_list_player.set_media_list(media_list)
media_list_player.play()
```

Comment: 申し訳ありません、記述不足でした。
通常の再生順とランダムとを使い分けたいのです。
編集前：

`media_list_player.play()`

編集後：

`a=input()
if a == "normal":
    media_list_player.play()
elif a == "random":
    ####曲順をシャッフル####
    rm.shuffle(media_list)
    media_list_player.play()`